# Is there a module in numpy which returns a polynomial object?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Using

```
from numpy.polynomial import polynomial as f
f.polyfromroots([2,2])
```

returns

```
[ 4. -4.  1.]
```

(the coefficients).

However, I could like it to return the polynomial x^2-4x+4 as an object.

Is there any such module available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's `Polynomial`:

```
poly = f.Polynomial(f.polyfromroots([2,2]))

poly(np.array([3, 5]))
# array([1., 9.])
```